# "File not found" while using JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access JSON file in php but browser is showing message as "File not found". am i missing anything? Apologies if it's very basic question as m new to php. Please note that m trying to run this `test.php` on a free hosting web server.

```
<?php

$data = '{
    "name": "Aragorn",
    "race": "Human"
}';

$character = json_decode($data);
echo $character->name;

?>
```

Comment: a URL is wrong somewhere (the adress at the top of your browser window), double-check it.

Comment: Code works fine. Your URL is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File not found doesn't have anything to do with json(encode/decode) , it has to do with the file not beeing at where exactly are you calling it.
Ex. if your folder structure is localhost/folder/file.php , and you try to access localhost/file.php it will give "File not found", if you try to access localhost/folder/fileX.php will give "File not found".

Comment: Thanks for your help! The server on which i was trying to run my code was down. Now it's up and could run my code as expected!